# Building a blank Cordova app is giving multiple errors

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform, visual-studio-cordova, mobile-application

im relatively new to VS and Cordova. Previously the environment had been set up for me but now i am trying to do it myself and I'm receiving multiple errors. The error log goes as follows

Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Grey. Hot.)

ripple.js (37,14889)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

favicon.ico (0,0)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

user-agent (0,0)

cordova :: Setting the user agent server side failed.
ripple.js (37,14889)

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

ripple.js (51,4377)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

ripple.js (51,4377)

cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.)

ripple.js (37,14889)

HTML1300: Navigation occurred

index.html
Current window: http://localhost:4400/index.html

I think the problem lies with ripple. I've spent the previous day trying to solve this and even reinstalled VS 2015 to no avail. Any help will be appreciated. It is probably a common error.

Comment: Does your app run correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Ripple throws these errors, but they're not important to pay attention to. Just quirks.

Answer (score 0):

The errors related to missing ripple.js and other files can be removed by adding this base meta tag to your head section of index.html:

```
<base href="/" target="_blank">
```

Add it **before the other tags** such as scripts and style declarations.